# Allow only one Chromium app instance

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, chromium

I have the Chromium source on Windows 7, and launch my custom app with the --app="..url" switch through a .bat file.  How can I prevent users from opening more than one instance of my Chromium app?  This includes opening the .exe directly, using the .bat file and by selecting "Chromium" from the jump list menu on the task bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is launched with the --app="...url" flag, then the following solution will prevent further "instances" of Chrome being opened.  I say "instances" because Chrome doesn't actually create new Chrome base processes.  Instead, it opens a new window with a process used for rendering that particular window.

So, when the app is in --app mode, all you need to do is prevent new windows from opening.  This can be accomplished by modifying the `OpenApplicationWindow()` method within the Chromium source code Application_launch class: `chrome/browser/ui/extensions/application_launch.cc`.

```
... 

OpenApplicationWindow(const AppLaunchParams& params) {
  browser = chrome::FindBrowserWithProfile(profile, params.desktop_type);

  #endif

  WebContents* web_contents;
  if (!browser) {
    browser = new Browser(browser_params);
    web_contents = chrome::AddSelectedTabWithURL(
       browser, url, content::PAGE_TRANSITION_AUTO_TOPLEVEL);
    web_contents->GetMutableRendererPrefs()->can_accept_load_drops = false;
    web_contents->GetRenderViewHost()->SyncRendererPrefs();
  }
  else {
    web_contents = browser->tab_strip_model()->GetActiveWebContents();
  }

   browser->window()->Show();

...
```

***NOTE: There should be some Windows 8 code in this method already.  The idea is to remove the conditions for Windows 8 Metro Mode, so new Windows are always prevented.**